# Summarize data with observations for all combinations of factors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Sometimes it is desirable to have a complete dataframe with observations for all combinations of grouping factors, even when these are absent in the original data (i.e. by filling these gaps with NA data).

Consider the following example with `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% dplyr::summarise(N = n())
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear     N
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2
```

When grouping by `cyl` and `gear`, observations are missing for `cyl=8` and `gear=4`. Is it possible to obtain this summary table in a straightforward, hopefully tidyverse-based, way that includes a row with NA observations for combinations of factors that are missing?. E.g. the desired output would be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear     N
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     4    NA
9     8     5     2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `complete` after removing the group attributes with `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(N = n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    complete(cyl, gear)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#    cyl  gear     N
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     4     3     1
#2     4     4     8
#3     4     5     2
#4     6     3     2
#5     6     4     4
#6     6     5     1
#7     8     3    12
#8     8     4    NA
#9     8     5     2
```

---

Or another option is to create a combination dataset with unique elements of the columns and then do a `left_join` (not as straightforward as the previous one)

```
crossing(cyl = unique(mtcars$cyl), gear = unique(mtcars$gear)) %>% 
    left_join(mtcars %>% 
                  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
                  dplyr::summarise(N = n()))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the groups to factor and use `count` (alternative for `group_by` with `summarise` `n()`) with `.drop = FALSE` it will complete missing observations.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear), factor) %>% count(cyl, gear, .drop = FALSE)

#  cyl   gear      N
#  <fct> <fct> <int>
#1 4     3         1
#2 4     4         8
#3 4     5         2
#4 6     3         2
#5 6     4         4
#6 6     5         1
#7 8     3        12
#8 8     4         0
#9 8     5         2
```